# Ring Allocator For Lockfree Update of Member Variable?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, lock-free

I have a class that stores the latest value of some incoming realtime data (around 150 million events/second).

Suppose it looks like this:

```
class DataState 
{
    Event latest_event;

  public:
  //pushes event atomically
  void push_event(const Event __restrict__* e);
  //pulls event atomically
  Event pull_event();
};
```

I need to be able to push events atomically and pull them with strict ordering guarantees. Now, I know I can use a spinlock, but given the massive event rate (over 100 million/second) and high degree of concurrency I'd prefer to use lockfree operations.

The problem is that `Event` is 64 bytes in size. There is no `CMPXCHG64B` instruction on any current X86 CPU (as of August '16). So if I use `std::atomic<Event>` I'd have to link to `libatomic` which uses mutexes under the hood (too slow).

So my solution was to instead atomically swap pointers to the value. Problem is dynamic memory allocation becomes a bottleneck with these event rates. So... I define something I call a "ring allocator":

```
/// @brief Lockfree Static short-lived allocator used for a ringbuffer
/// Elements are guaranteed to persist only for "size" calls to get_next()
template<typename T> class RingAllocator {
  T *arena;
  std::atomic_size_t arena_idx;
  const std::size_t arena_size;
 public:
  /// @brief Creates a new RingAllocator
  /// @param size The number of elements in the underlying arena. Make this large enough to avoid overwriting fresh data
  RingAllocator<T>(std::size_t size) : arena_size(size)
  {
  //allocate pool
  arena = new T[size];
  //zero out pool
  std::memset(arena, 0, sizeof(T) * size);
  arena_idx = 0;
  }

  ~RingAllocator()
  {
  delete[] arena;
  }

  /// @brief Return next element's pointer. Thread-safe
  /// @return pointer to next available element
  T *get_next()
  {
      return &arena[arena_idx.exchange(arena_idx++ % arena_size)];
  }
};
```

Then I could have my DataState class look like this:

```
class DataState 
{
    std::atomic<Event*> latest_event;
    RingAllocator<Event> event_allocator;
  public:
  //pushes event atomically
  void push_event(const Event __restrict__* e)
  {
      //store event
      Event *new_ptr = event_allocator.get_next()
      *new_ptr = *e;
      //swap event pointers
      latest_event.store(new_ptr, std::memory_order_release);
  }
  //pulls event atomically
  Event pull_event()
  {
      return *(latest_event.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
  }
};
```

As long as I size my ring allocator to the max # of threads that may concurrently call the functions, there's no risk of overwriting data that pull_event could return. Plus everything's super localized so indirection won't cause bad cache performance. Any possible pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: If this code is working and you are asking for possible improvements or risks, you should better post your question at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What does MM stand for?  M meaning "mega" (million) I know about; if you mean a million million, why not say "T" (tera)?

Comment: @MartinBonner edited to say million. Just common in the financial industry to use the MM suffix to represent million. Not actually sure why.

Comment: Are you sure this is all helping? Intuitively, it seems a fixed structure protected by a mutex would be faster.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so, I did benchmark using three variants of a lock:
1. std::atomic<Event> linked with libatomic (uses pthread_mutex under the hood). 2. a spinlock. 3. lockfree swaps (this code). The mutex is extremely slow due to the context switch it often requires. The spinlock is faster but serializes reads. The lockfree variant is around 30% faster (I suspect looking at cachegrind that it's due to the improved cache coherency)

Comment: How do you define 'strict order'? The order in which push_event() is called? It is quite possible that one thread calls push_event() multiple times before the OS switches to another thread. Until then other threads will not even have a chance to check if there is any event to push. A much better approach would be to have each event timestamped. Each thread can have it's own latest event. Then you can compare timestamps to select the latest event.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis on a high level, how would something like that be implemented? The threads are guaranteed to get events in strictly chronological order (each thread has at most one event at a time it can push, and they all pop from a FIFO ringbuffer).

Comment: If event data does not already have a timestamp then there is no way to actually know which event came first if they come at a rate that is faster than the rate of thread switching. Usually at such high rates there is already a timestamp, usually provided by hardware.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis each event has a microsecond-level timestamp. So this is a possibility

Comment: Regarding the FIFO buffer, it is still possible that a thread gets an event from the FIFO, then gets switched out. Another thread gets a few events from the FIFO and pushes them before being switched out and so on until  the 1st thread takes control again and pushes the event it got just before being switched out. The order of events has changed

Comment: Regarding the microsecond timestamp, it can only handle 1M samples per second max.

Comment: If you can run this on a CPU with non-buggy/disabled TSX (Skylake, and maybe some later-model Broadwell), [transactional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory) makes it possible to compose multiple operations into a single atomic operation that involves much more than 16B of memory (where cmpxchg16B is the current largest possible atomic RMW size on x86-64).  See also http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-tm/.  You'd have to see how well it performed, compared to pointer-swaps or locking.

Comment: Alright, I worked around all this by adding a 64 bit sequence number to the events that is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing. I keep track of the latest sequence number in my DataState class as an atomic<std::uint64_t> so any attempts to write an older event will first check this variable and drop the write if it's old. This guarantees never inserting a stale event.

@PeterCordes sadly this is running on a v3 Xeon E5 (Haswell) where the microcode update disabled TSX.

Comment: FYI: `arena = new T[size]{}` would eliminate your need for memset.

Comment: yeah @kfsone each `RingAllocator` only gets created at the start of the program so there didn't seem to be a point in optimizing it. I can honestly just eliminate that line anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The `DataState` class:

I thought it was going to be a stack or queue, but it isn't, so `push` / `pull` don't seem like good names for methods.  (Or else the implementation is totally bogus).

It's just a latch that lets you read the last event that any thread stored.

There's nothing to stop two writes in a row from overwriting an element that's never been read.  There's also nothing to stop you reading the same element twice.

If you just need somewhere to copy small blocks of data, a ring buffer does seem like a decent approach.  But if you don't want to lose events, I don't think you can use it this way.  Instead, just get a ring buffer entry, then copy to it and use it there.  So the only atomic operation should be incrementing the ring buffer position index.

---

#### The ring buffer

You can make `get_next()` much more efficient.  This line does an atomic post-increment (fetch_add) and an atomic exchange:

```
return &arena[arena_idx.exchange(arena_idx++ % arena_size)];
```

I'm not even sure it's safe, because the xchg can maybe step on the fetch_add from another thread.  Anyway, even if it's safe, it's not ideal.

You don't need that.  Make sure the arena_size is always a power of 2, then you don't need to modulo the shared counter.  You can just let it go, and have every thread modulo it for their own use.  It will eventually wrap, but it's a binary integer so it will wrap at a power of 2, which is a multiple of your arena size.

I'd suggest storing an AND-mask instead of a size, so there's no risk of the `%` compiling to anything other than an `and` instruction, even if it's not a compile-time constant.  This makes sure we avoid a 64-bit integer `div` instruction.

```
template<typename T> class RingAllocator {
  T *arena;
  std::atomic_size_t arena_idx;
  const std::size_t size_mask;   // maybe even make this a template parameter?
 public:
  RingAllocator<T>(std::size_t size) 
    : arena_idx(0),  size_mask(size-1)
  {
     // verify that size is actually a power of two, so the mask is all-ones in the low bits, and all-zeros in the high bits.
     // so that i % size == i & size_mask for all i
   ...
  }

  ...
  T *get_next() {
      size_t idx = arena_idx.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);  // still atomic, but we don't care which order different threads take blocks in
      idx &= size_mask;   // modulo our local copy of the idx
      return &arena[idx];
  }
};
```

---

**Allocating the arena would be more efficient if you used `calloc`** instead of new + memset.  The OS already zeros pages before giving them to user-space processes (to prevent information leakage), so writing them all is just wasted work.

```
  arena = new T[size];
  std::memset(arena, 0, sizeof(T) * size);

  // vs.

  arena = (T*)calloc(size, sizeof(T));
```

Writing the pages yourself does fault them in, so they're all wired to real physical pages, instead of just copy-on-write mappings for a system-wide shared physical zero page (like they are after new/malloc/calloc).  On a NUMA system, the physical page chosen might depend on which thread actually touched the page, rather than which thread did the allocation.  But since you're reusing the pool, the first core to write a page might not be the one that ends up using it most.

Maybe something to look for in microbenchmarks / perf counters.

Comment: thanks. This combined with the suggestion to use a unique sequence identifier helped address my problems.

Question: shouldn't the mask be `size - 1` since `x % y == (x & (y-1))` (when y is a power of 2)?

Comment: Yes.  I was picturing the actual code as being `size_mask(size_to_mask(size))`, where size_to_mask checks that it actually *is* a power of two.  But you could just do that check in the constructor *after* the initialization of the const member.

Answer (score 1):

> As long as I size my ring allocator to the max # of threads that may concurrently call the functions, there's no risk of overwriting data that pull_event could return. .... Any possible pitfalls with this approach?

The pitfall is, IIUC, that your statement is wrong.

If I have just 2 threads, and 10 elements in the ring buffer, the first thread could call pull_event once, and be "mid-pulling", and then the second thread could call push 10 times, overwriting what thread 1 is pulling.

Again, assuming I understand your code correctly.

Also, as mentioned above,

```
return &arena[arena_idx.exchange(arena_idx++ % arena_size)];
```

that `arena_idx++` inside the exchange on the same variable, just looks wrong.  And in fact is wrong.  Two threads could increment it - ThreadA increments to 8 and threadB increments to 9, and then threadB exchanges it to 9, then threadA exchanges it to 8.  whoops.

atomic(op1) @ atomic(op2) != atomic(op1 @ op2)

I worry about what else is wrong in code not shown.  I don't mean that as an insult - lock-free is just not easy.

Comment: Yeah, instead of two operations (an atomic increment and an exchange) I'm now doing a fetch_add with the modulo operation computed by the thread itself (as suggested by Peter Cordes). Also making this single-threaded to deal with the scheduling issue.

Comment: @alfalfasprout: If you make it single-threaded, you don't need arena_idx to be atomic.  But what threads are going to be using the data?  If a thread sleeps for 10ms, a reasonable-sized ring buffer will could have wrapped around and overwritten the event it's half way through reading.  Unless you mean you're just giving up on multi-threading entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any of the C++ Disruptor (Java) ports that are available?

[disruptor--](https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--)

[disruptor](https://github.com/newcoder/disruptor)

Although they are not complete ports they may offer all that you need. I am currently working on a more fully featured port however it's not quite ready.

Comment: Actually, I have used disruptor-- in the past. Unfortunately, it isn't the right fit for this use case (each thread should get a unique event, eg; a FIFO queue rather than PUB/SUB).

Comment: The original Disruptor pattern supports pub sub. i.e 1PMC. As well as MPMC. The former is how we use it in our C++ port to handle network I/O.

Comment: indeed it does but I don't want duplicate events among threads. Pub sub is "everything to everyone" (sometimes with filtering on the client-side). I want events dispatched to individual threads and not duplicated.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. Disruptor absolutely supports FIFO. That is, the incoming events are processed by the next available consumer. i.e. Each event is only processed once, by one consumer.